# Node.js sequelize model file don't take into account configuration

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have the model file which looks as follows:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  let User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        this.belongsToMany(models.role, {
          through: {
            model: 'user_role'
          },
          foreignKey: 'user_id'
        })
      }
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'user',
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true
  }
)
return User
}
```

When I try to make any query on this model I get an error, `SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'sc.users' doesn't exist`. It is true that database `users` doesn't exist, its name is `user`. I added information about it in my model (`tableName: 'user'`).

I don't understand why sequelize don't read my configuration options.
How should I prepare my model file in order to sqeuelize could read configurations from it?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've never used table name overriding, but as far as I can see from the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration) and tests [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/2fc43c4cd1efe7f0ba649a7d6572119502fb0a42/test/integration/model.test.js#L39) and [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/2fc43c4cd1efe7f0ba649a7d6572119502fb0a42/test/integration/model.test.js#L44), you need to also set `freezeTableName` to `true` in order to use the table name you gave to your model, so now your model would look like:

```
'use strict'

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  let User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        this.belongsToMany(models.role, {
          through: {
            model: 'user_role'
          },
          foreignKey: 'user_id'
        })
      }
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName: 'user',
    timestamps: false,
    underscored: true
  })
  return User
}
```